# Trying to create a shortcut to remove empty lines from the notes section of a Reminder?

Tags: shortcuts-app

Any idea if the above is possible? My reminders are synced with Exchange (work reasons) and when initially created in Outlook always end up with a bunch of empty lines in the “notes” field that only show up in Reminders. I can manually remove them, but am wondering if there is a way to automate the process.

Thanks!